# INSERT Error Python MySQL Connector: Failed executing the operation

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I am scraping a shopify store using the products.json page. Attempting to insert the scraped products into my MySQL DB using the Python connector, but hitting below error:

> Something went wrong: Failed executing the operation; b'`Name`'

Code is below:

````
import json
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
import ScraperConfig as conf

class myScraper():

    def __init__(self, baseurl):
        self.baseurl = baseurl

    def downloadjson(self, page):
        r = requests.get(self.baseurl + f'products.json?limit=250&page={page}', timeout=5)
        if r.status_code != 200:
            print('Bad status code', r.status_code)
        if len(r.json()['products']) > 0:
            data = r.json()['products']
            return data
        else:
            return

    def parsejson(self, jsondata):
        products = []

        for prod in jsondata:
            vendor = prod['vendor']
            name = prod['title']
            handle = prod['handle']
            createdDateTime = prod['created_at']
            description = prod['body_html']
            productType = prod['product_type']
            for images in prod['images']:
                vendorProductId = images['product_id']
                try:
                    imageURL = images['src']
                except:
                    imageURL = 'None'
            for variant in prod['variants']:
                item = {
                    'name': name,
                    'handle': handle,
                    'description': description,
                    'productVariantId': variant['id'],
                    'createdDateTime': createdDateTime,
                    'productType': productType,
                    'vendorProductId': vendorProductId,
                    'imageURL': imageURL,
                    'price': variant['price'],
                    'salePrice': variant['compare_at_price'],
                    'available': variant['available'],
                    'updatedDateTime': variant['updated_at'],
                    'vendor': vendor
                }
                products.append(item)
        return products
        
def main():
    scrape = Scraper('https://www.someshopifysite.com/')
    results = []
    for page in range(1,2):
        data = scrape.downloadjson(page)
        print('Getting page: ', page)
        try:
            results.append(scrape.parsejson(data))
        except:
            print(f'Completed, total pages = {page - 1}')
            break
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
        user=conf.user,
        host=conf.host,
        passwd=conf.passwd,
        database=conf.database)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    products = main()
    totals = [item for i in products for item in i]
    for p in totals:
        sql = """INSERT INTO `table` (`Name`, `Handle`, `Descritpion`, `VariantId`, `CreatedDateTime`, `ProductType`, `VendorProductId`, `ImageURL`, `Price`, `SalePrice`, `Available`, `UpdatedDateTime`, `Vendor`)          
        VALUES (%(`Name`)s, %(`Handle`)s, %(`Descritpion`)s, %(`VariantId`)s, %(`CreatedDateTime`)s, %(`ProductType`)s, %(`VendorProductId`)s, %(`ImageURL`)s, %(`Price`)s, %(`SalePrice`)s, %(`Available`)s, %(`UpdatedDateTime`)s, %(`Vendor`)s)"""
            
        try:
            cursor.executemany(sql, totals)
            
            print('Committed to DB')
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
                    print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))
        db.commit() ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Remove backticks from the following and all similar parts of the query:

```
%(`Name`)s
```

In general I'd remove backticks except for quoting column names that map to keywords.

Comment: Tried that. No dice unfortunately. Error: Something went wrong: Failed executing the operation; b'Name'